# How can I access the key of dictionary ,with matching values of it with another external list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to access the key of dictionary by checking equality of its value with an element of another list.

```
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

word = '26kk15'

d={'3':['1','2'],'4':['5','6'],'s':['k','l']}
keys=list(d.keys())
l=len(d)
c=0
nl=split(word)
for k in range(0,len(nl)):
    for iu in d.values():
        for j in iu:
            if(j==nl[k]):
                print(keys[c])
        c+=1
```

I am getting list index out of range error.
And if I remove the outer for loop it will give me output as 3 4 s,while I want \n3\n4\ns\ns\n3\n4.

Comment: FYI you can just use `list(word)` to convert a string to a list.

Comment: You increment `c` `len(nl) * len(keys)` times. Since that's longer than `keys`, you get out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` is going out of range because you don't reset it to `0` each time you iterate over `d.values()`.

But there's no need for all those extra lists. Use `.items()` to iterate over both the keys and values of the dictionary, so you can print the key when you find a matching value.

You should use the `in` operator to test whether something is in the list, without another nested loop.

```
for letter in word:
    for key, chars in d.items():
        if letter in chars:
            print(key)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

in Python it's easier to iterate through a collection directly rather than getting it's length, iterate through numeric indices and then lookup up the item back again via index. You can even iterate through a string directly without converting it to a list.

```
d = {'3': ['1', '2'], '4': ['5', '6'], 's': ['k', 'l']}

word = '26kk15'

for needle in word:
    for key, haystack in d.items():
        # check if the character is in the dict item
        if needle in haystack:
            # if it is, print it and `break` the search loop for given character
            print(key)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to obtain what you need using python regex:

```
import re
word = '26kk15'

d={'3':['1','2'],'4':['5','6'],'s':['k','l'], 'b': ['8', '9']}
for key, values in d.items():
    # Check if elements in 'values' are part of 'word'
    if re.search(r"|".join(values), word):
        print (key)
```

Output:

```
3
4
s
```